# Removing disabled HTML attribute from a button does not allow to click it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this button component in my React application:

```
<button onClick={() =>alert('hi')} disabled={true}>test</button>
```

I expected when I will remove `disabled` attribute in browser like:

```
<button disabled>test</button>
```

to:

```
<button>test</button>
```

The button should be clicked and alert should appear but it did not happen.

Why is the button not triggering alert message after removing the attribute inside the browser?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What do you mean with `when i will remove disabled attribute in browser`? Do you mean opening the developer console and manually removing the disabled attribute from the element?

Comment: @trixn, click right click on the button, select `inspect` and remove the attribute in the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<button>` you render with react is not the actual DOM element but a built-in component, that manages its state internally. So the props you pass to that component only get reflected in the DOM when react re-renders it when props or state have changed.

But React doesn't know you removed the `disabled` attribute in the DOM. From the perspective of react, the button is still disabled and click events are therefore suppressed. When managing the DOM with react you should not try to manipulate the DOM from outside as react will not be aware of any changes and they will be overridden with every render.

Also events on built-in components are managed by reacts own event handling. So the handler you passed to the `<button>` component is not the same as if you provided it directly to the DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please also refer to some links as well from where you got this info or how can I google this topic? I want to look more into it. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

As per your code, I can see that you did not remove the **disabled** attribute.
You only removed the **{true}** part. Keeping the **disabled** attribute, even if it is not set to true, will still disable the button, which is why it is not getting triggered. Try this :-

```
<button onClick={() => alert("hi")}>test</button>
```

Comment: i removed the attribute and i get this inside the browser <button>test</button> . But it is not triggering the onclick.

Comment: By inside the browser do you mean chrome devtool?

Comment: yes, click right click on the button, select `inspect` and remove the attribute in the browser.